# Moving from a matrix of character names to a vector of those names (for fMRI data)

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a lower triangular matrix of fMRI network connectivities of sum(1:235), so there are 27730 values. I have these values, however, I want to cbind another vector that has the names of these regions of interest (ROIs), but I'm not sure how I can move from the 236 vector of these ROIs to the filled out 27730 vector.

So the connections should go like this: SN1-SN2, SN1-SN3…..SN1-CB4, SN2-SN3 …. SN2-CB4, SN3-SN4 …SN3-CB4 and so on. If you take all the unique connections, then the first of 236 ROIs has 235 connections, second ROI has 234 connections, third ROI has 233 connections and so on. So the total unique connections are sum(1:235) = 27730.

Per a comment, though, I have changed the vector to only contain 7 of these values.

Thus, I've also changed the connectivities to have sum(1:8) values.

Thanks much!

```r
roi <- c("SN2", "SN3", "SN4", "SN5", "CON1", "CON2", "CB4")
```

```
connectivities <- rnorm(1:28)
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question the improves the formatting, though the last two seem suspect: `"CB3 "`, etc, with a space within the string; this is different from all other strings, so I wanted to verify. Please [edit] your question and correct those if that is in error. I edited it because code really reads better when fixed-width, really-long data doesn't need multiple rows for us to just copy it, and the actual code underneath was less-usable. Thanks!

Comment: Realistically, though, you don't need 235 elements to make your point, you can get the same thing from (say) 10. It really helps the process (both you learning programming and us helping you) if the problems are much smaller: solve with fewer data and apply to more data.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that edit!; I overlooked that. I checked the code, and it is correct, so I deleted the space.

Comment: Point taken...I've changed the included code. I lack the terminology, here, to really explain what I am trying to do, but I'm sure it's a pretty run-of-the-mill operation. Sorry if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```r
m <- outer(roi, roi, paste, sep = "-")
m
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]        [,6]        [,7]      
# [1,] "SN2-SN2"  "SN2-SN3"  "SN2-SN4"  "SN2-SN5"  "SN2-CON1"  "SN2-CON2"  "SN2-CB4" 
# [2,] "SN3-SN2"  "SN3-SN3"  "SN3-SN4"  "SN3-SN5"  "SN3-CON1"  "SN3-CON2"  "SN3-CB4" 
# [3,] "SN4-SN2"  "SN4-SN3"  "SN4-SN4"  "SN4-SN5"  "SN4-CON1"  "SN4-CON2"  "SN4-CB4" 
# [4,] "SN5-SN2"  "SN5-SN3"  "SN5-SN4"  "SN5-SN5"  "SN5-CON1"  "SN5-CON2"  "SN5-CB4" 
# [5,] "CON1-SN2" "CON1-SN3" "CON1-SN4" "CON1-SN5" "CON1-CON1" "CON1-CON2" "CON1-CB4"
# [6,] "CON2-SN2" "CON2-SN3" "CON2-SN4" "CON2-SN5" "CON2-CON1" "CON2-CON2" "CON2-CB4"
# [7,] "CB4-SN2"  "CB4-SN3"  "CB4-SN4"  "CB4-SN5"  "CB4-CON1"  "CB4-CON2"  "CB4-CB4" 

m[upper.tri(m)]
#  [1] "SN2-SN3"   "SN2-SN4"   "SN3-SN4"   "SN2-SN5"   "SN3-SN5"   "SN4-SN5"   "SN2-CON1"  "SN3-CON1"  "SN4-CON1" 
# [10] "SN5-CON1"  "SN2-CON2"  "SN3-CON2"  "SN4-CON2"  "SN5-CON2"  "CON1-CON2" "SN2-CB4"   "SN3-CB4"   "SN4-CB4"  
# [19] "SN5-CB4"   "CON1-CB4"  "CON2-CB4"
```

Because there are 7 in `roi`, the first element (`"SN2"`) has six connections; second element (`"SN3"`) has five; etc ... producing 21 total connections.

---

Another way, using (and improving on) Ben's use of `combn`:

```r
apply(combn(roi,2), 2, paste, collapse = "-")
#  [1] "SN2-SN3"   "SN2-SN4"   "SN2-SN5"   "SN2-CON1"  "SN2-CON2"  "SN2-CB4"   "SN3-SN4"   "SN3-SN5"   "SN3-CON1" 
# [10] "SN3-CON2"  "SN3-CB4"   "SN4-SN5"   "SN4-CON1"  "SN4-CON2"  "SN4-CB4"   "SN5-CON1"  "SN5-CON2"  "SN5-CB4"  
# [19] "CON1-CON2" "CON1-CB4"  "CON2-CB4"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the "outer" function.

Comment: `outer` is a nice outer-cartesian-product function, useful in times like this. It's relatively efficient, though with user-defined functions it can be hard to work with.

Comment: Quick question: when you changed the vector "roi" in my question, what code did you use, other than just adding the ``` ```. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the "\ \" between all of the ROIs after using paste, but can't figure out how.

Comment: I copied the *formatted* html (which hid the backslashes, just presented quotes) and then pasted into the code-block as-is. I have never had to use that technique before, yours was the first time I've seen all of the back-slashed dbl-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a smaller set of values (7). For 7 values, there are 21 combinations: `6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 45`.

```
roi <- c("SN2", "SN3", "SN4", "SN5", "CON1", "CON2", "CB4")
```

The `combn()` function generates the desired output as a matrix:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]   [,10]  [,11]
[1,] "SN2" "SN2" "SN2" "SN2"  "SN2"  "SN2" "SN3" "SN3" "SN3"  "SN3"  "SN3"
[2,] "SN3" "SN4" "SN5" "CON1" "CON2" "CB4" "SN4" "SN5" "CON1" "CON2" "CB4"
     [,12] [,13]  [,14]  [,15] [,16]  [,17]  [,18] [,19]  [,20]  [,21] 
[1,] "SN4" "SN4"  "SN4"  "SN4" "SN5"  "SN5"  "SN5" "CON1" "CON1" "CON2"
[2,] "SN5" "CON1" "CON2" "CB4" "CON1" "CON2" "CB4" "CON2" "CB4"  "CB4"
```

To get your final desired output, transpose the matrix, convert to data.frame, and use `unite()` from `tidyr` to stitch the two roi values together.

```
library(dplyr) # for the piper %>%
library(tidy)
combn(roi, 2) %>%
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  unite(col = "combination", sep = "-") 

    combination
1      SN2-SN3
2      SN2-SN4
3      SN2-SN5
4     SN2-CON1
5     SN2-CON2
6      SN2-CB4
7      SN3-SN4
8      SN3-SN5
9     SN3-CON1
10    SN3-CON2
11     SN3-CB4
12     SN4-SN5
13    SN4-CON1
14    SN4-CON2
15     SN4-CB4
16    SN5-CON1
17    SN5-CON2
18     SN5-CB4
19   CON1-CON2
20    CON1-CB4
21    CON2-CB4
```

Comment: Good thought to use `combn`, see my answer for a way to use it without the overhead of `%>%` and data.framing. Nice!